# Confusing text when editing .bash_profile

Tags: bash, terminal, python, vi

I am running MacOS v.10.13.6, and in Terminal I was installing pipenv by following a tutorial. As part of the installation I went to edit bash_profile with vi editor in order to add 3 directories to PATH.

This is my first time using vi and adding directories to PATH, so if it is just my ignorance then I apologize, but the result is a bunch of text that I didn't expect, and no searches I perform on any portion of the text have yielded any insight.

This is the command I type to edit bash_profile:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

And this is the result:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Miniconda3 4.6.14 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/nathanielgrundmann/miniconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/nathanielgrundmann/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/nathanielgrundmann/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/nathanielgrundmann/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

This text is followed by what I expected to see: a lot of empty lines with tildas down the left side of the window which I recognize as the vi editor.

I close vi without writing, and if I repeat the command I get the same thing.

I have an intuition that this is displaying because I recently installed Miniconda which came with Python 3.7 AND I already had Python 3.7 installed from some months ago. So perhaps a duplicate installation of Python is triggering this?

Apologies if I'm leaving out something, it's my first question here, and on a topic that I'm just starting to learn. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly is the part that you did not expect?

Comment: The entire block of text that I call "the result" of the command: 

vi ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is just the current contents of your ~/.bash_profile file. To confirm this, run `more ~/.bash_profile`, and you should see the same thing. The first 4 lines were added automatically when you installed Python 3.7 to make sure you'd be able to use the newly installed Python; the rest was added similarly by the Miniconda3 installer.

Solution: make a backup of the file in case anything goes wrong, then edit it again in `vi` and just move down to the bottom and add your new commands after what's already there. I'd leave a blank line in between (and between the Python and Miniconda parts as well), so it's visually easier to tell where the sections start and end.

Comment: Thank you @gordon for clarifying this! I appreciate your help.